# Hadoop MapReduce producing log files only after certain interval?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So I have been trying to run a Hadoop MapReduce job for a while, and after it successfully started running (all errors sorted out), I wanted to check the log files for the stdout which is captured in the log files, but somehow I see that the log files aren't being generated every time. (some times it comes, other time it doesn't)

I was using an output directory (`/user/hduser/output_dir`), and deleting the contents and using that again (to avoid keeping track of so many output directories) but the log files indicate the time when the last change was made to it, and that does not match the last time I ran the job.
Also, the log files in `/user/hduser/output_dir` does not match with `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs`
Is it a known problem, and is there any solution to this? I did not find the answer to it anywhere. 
Thanks for the help.!

EDIT - So we found out that the log files are being written only after certain intervals of time, so if a job is run twice within this time then new log files aren't written for that. Why would this be so, and how can I override it using some configuration changes, if it's possible?

Comment: How many nodes are in your cluster? task logs will be located in the logs folder on the node the task ran on - possibly explaining the inconsistent presence of your log files.

Comment: There's only 2 nodes. And only one node was being used as the input file was pretty small.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that the missing logs are not on the second 'other' node?